# ObjectDataSource is selecting before Drop Down List is populate with data

Tags: c#, webforms, .net-4.0, dropdown, objectdatasource

I bind my DropDownList during first Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Function.LoopChangeControlMtText(this.Controls);

        BindProcessingDepartment();
        BindDropDownListYear();
        if (DropDownListProcessingDepartment.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (DropDownListYear.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                BindGridViewUploadedItemNoCommitment();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void BindDropDownListYear()
{
    MTConfig mtConfig = new MTConfig();
    DataTable mtCreatedYear = new DataTable();
    mtCreatedYear = mtConfig.getMtCreatedYear();
    if (mtCreatedYear == null)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alertFailProcessDeptBind", "alert('Failed to get " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["systemNameShortFormWithoutE"].Trim() + " created year.\\nPlease contact MIS.\\nContact info. at the bottom of the page.');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownListYear.DataSource = mtCreatedYear;
        DropDownListYear.DataMember = "MtCreatedYear";
        DropDownListYear.DataValueField = "MtCreatedYear";
        DropDownListYear.SelectedIndex = 0;
        DropDownListYear.DataBind();
    }
}
```

But my object data source perform selecting before the drop down list is populate with data. The `SelectedValue` below is empty during the first select.

```
protected void objectDataSourceUploadedItemWithoutCommitment_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        e.InputParameters["CreatedYear"] = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListYear.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHandler.LogError(logger, ex);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", "Error occurred during objectDataSourceUploadedItemWithoutCommitment_Selecting!", true);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the order of `objectDataSourceUploadedItemWithoutCommitment_Selecting` and `Page_Load`?

How else can I deal with this other than `DropDownListYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select year", "0"))` to force user to select a year?

Answer (score 0):

You can done it on front side using `AppendDataBoundItems="True"` property:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListYear" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem>Please select year</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This will automatically append the first item with your all other items populated from DataSource.

Comment: Not working, `objectDataSourceUploadedItemWithoutCommitment_Selecting` still happen before first `Page_Load` hence there are no data in DropDownList.